# Different Descriptions of the Torus

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that different representations of the Torus are homeomorphic.

> Let I=[0,1] be the unit interval. Show that the following spaces are homeomorphic:
>
> i) $S^1 \times S^1$
>
> ii) $R^2 \ /\sim$ where we define $(x,y) \ \sim \ (x',y')$ to hold if and only if $ (x-x',y-y') \in Z \times Z$.
>
> iii) $I \times I \ /\sim$ where $\sim$ is generated by $(x,0) \sim (x,1)$ and $(0,y) \sim (1,y)$.

I wanted to prove that

iii) is homeomorphic to i)

iii) is homeomorphic to i),

but I am stuck at proving the latter.

My idea to prove the latter statement was this. Consider the projections

$\pi: R^2 \to R^2/ \sim$

$\phi: I \times I \to I \times I / \sim$

and the inclusion map

$i: I \times I \to R^2$

Prove that

a) $\pi \circ i$ is continous and surjective

b) $I \times I$ is compact

c) $R^2/ \sim$ is hausdorff.

d) $\pi \circ i$ is an identification map (follows from a)-c)).

e) There is a homeomorphism from $I \times I$ to $R^2/ \sim$. Do this by using the statement

> Let $q_i: X \to Y_i$ be two identification maps. If for all x,x' $\in$ X we have $q_0(x)=q_0(x')$ iff $q_1(x)=q_1(x')$ then there is a unique map $h: Y_0 \to Y_1$ such that $h \circ q_0=q_1$. h is a  homeomorphism.

My problem lies with proving that $R^2/ \sim$ is hausdorff. Given two elements [a], [b] in $R^2/ \sim$ I can find disjoint open neighborhoods $U_0$ and $V_0$ in $R^2$ where $a \in U_0$ and $b \in V_0$. For every point a' in $R^2 $ that is identified with a I can also find disjoint open neighborhoods $U_1$ and $V_1$ where $a \in U_1$ and $a' \in V_1$. But I have trouble defining disjoint neighborhoods in $R^2/ \sim$ of [a] and [b] that are also disjoint. I thought about defining $U=\pi(U_0 \cap U_1)$ and $V=\pi(V_0 \cap V_1)$, but these are not necessarily going to be open, as $\pi$ is not an open map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that $\pi$ is not an open map, but it is. To see this, let $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ be open. It suffices to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open because we have the quotient topology on $\mathbb R^2/\sim$. For $(m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2$ let $T_{(m,n)} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be the translation $(x,y) \mapsto (x+m,y+n)$. This is a homeomorphism, thus $U_{(m,n)} = T_{(m,n)}(U)$ is open. Hence $U^* = \bigcup_{(m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2} U_{(m,n)}$ is open. We claim
$$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = U^*$$
which will finish the proof.

We have

$$(x,y) \in \pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) \Leftrightarrow \pi(x,y) \in \pi(U) \Leftrightarrow \pi(x,y) = \pi(x',y') \text{ for some } (x',y') \in U \\ \Leftrightarrow  (x,y) \sim (x',y')  \text{ for some } (x',y') \in U \\ \Leftrightarrow  (x,y) = (x'+m,y'+n) \text{ for some } (x,'y') \in U \text{ and some } (m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow  (x,y)  \in T_{(m,n)}(U) = U_{(m,n)} \text{ for some } (m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in U^* $$